# What is the distance between branches of a spiral?

Tags: geometry

Given a point on a spiral is it possible to define the distance from one branch of the spiral to the next branch of the spiral?  For example this distance on an Archimedean Spiral is always $ 2\pi b$. Is there a way to define this distance for logarithmic spirals? For example a spiral with the equation $r = ae^{b\theta}$?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mupM0.png]

Comment: How are you defining distance? The distance between the next spiral at the point where it intersects the ray passing through the origin and the point in question?

Comment: For many spirals, a ray emanating from the spiral origin is a reasonable tool for measure of this distance, but for a logarithmic spiral it may be valuable to consider the tangent lines at the two arms in question and find a distance which uses a weighted average of those tangents.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think the ray passing through the origin feels like a reasonable place to start.